# How to access local variables in pycord button callbacks?

Tags: python, discord, pycord

PROBLEM:

I am facing this issue and I am kinda stuck and dont know what to do. So I have a local variable which I wanna use in pycord button callback function but even after making it global I get the following error.

CODE:

```
@commands.command()
async def test(self, ctx):
    but = Button(label="Increase", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    view = Myview()
    view.add_item(but)
    cur_value = 0 #local variable which i wanna access and change value of.
    async def but_callback(interaction):
        global cur_value
        cur_value += 1
        async interaction.response.send_message(f"Current value = {cur_value}")
        return
    but.callback = but_callback
    await ctx.send("Click me", view=view)
    await view.wait()
```

ERROR:

```
NameError: name 'cur_value' is not defined
```

Comment: can't you just remove `global cur_value`?

Comment: Initially it wasn't in the code but still i faced the same issue and upon searching some time I found that it should be mentioned inside a function to access cur_value

Comment: Right, check if switching `global` with `nonlocal` helps.

Comment: Might aswell put this here, just for reference: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-local-nonlocal-variables